# Using typedef of template class in another class

Tags: c++, templates

I got the following challenge.

I got a template class that defines a boost shared_ptr as a type.

```
template<typename T, int a, int b>
class AbstractSmth{

public:

typedef boost::shared_ptr< AbstractSmth > ABSTR_SMTH;

...
};
```

and an other also template class, in which I want to use that type. I know the following syntax works.

```
template<typename T, int a, int b>
class AbstractOtherThing{

public:

    typename AbstractSmth<T,a,b>::ABSTR_SMTH p_smth;

    void myFancyFunction(typename AbstractSmoother<T,a, b>::ABSTR_SMTH baz){
    ...
}

};
```

Is it possible to use that type as a typedef inside that class? Maybe something like this:

```
template<typename T, int a, int b>
class AbstractOtherThing{

public:

    using typename AbstractSmth<T,a,b>::ABSTR_SMTH;

    ABSTR_SMTH p_smth;

    void myFancyFunction(ABSTR_SMTH baz){
    ...
}

};
```

Best regards and happy new year!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure.

Oldschool:

```
typedef typename AbstractSmth<T,a,b>::ABSTR_SMTH ABSTR_SMTH;
```

C++11:

```
using ABSTR_SMTH = typename AbstractSmth<T,a,b>::ABSTR_SMTH;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
typedef typename AbstractSmth<T,a,b>::ABSTR_SMTH ABSTR_SMTH;
```

or C++11 way:

```
using ABSTR_SMTH = typename AbstractSmth<T,a,b>::ABSTR_SMTH;
```